# Assigning specific values to node numbers in Python

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I have a list of `nodes`. I want to assign values to the node numbers using `A`. For example, `node 1` takes `A[0]`, `node 2` takes `A[1]` and so on. Basically, it should create a matrix `T (shape= (3,3))` which I can plot using `matplotlib.pyplot`. The expected output is attached.

```
import numpy as np

nodes={(0, 0): 1,
 (0, 1): 2,
 (0, 2): 3,
 (1, 0): 4,
 (1, 1): 5,
 (1, 2): 6,
 (2, 0): 7,
 (2, 1): 8,
 (2, 2): 9}

A=np.array([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90])
```

This is how the matrix should look like based on the indices in `nodes`.

```
T = np.array([[10, 20, 30],
              [40, 50, 60],
              [70, 80 ,90]])
```

The expected output is

[image: Output]

Comment: `[ ({(0, 0): 1}, 10), ({(0, 1): 2}, 20), ({(0, 2): 3}, 30), ...... ]`  Do you need output like this to plot the chart? What do mean by assigning value of node from A?

Comment: I have edited the post. I hope it clarifies better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not vectorized, so might not be the most efficient, but here is a way:

Please note that the `nodes` values seems to be 1-indexed instead of standard 0-indexed, hence the `idx-1` in `out[pos] = A[idx - 1]`.

```py
import numpy as np

nodes = {
    (0, 0): 1,
    (0, 1): 2,
    (0, 2): 3,
    (1, 0): 4,
    (1, 1): 5,
    (1, 2): 6,
    (2, 0): 7,
    (2, 1): 8,
    (2, 2): 9,
}

A = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
T = np.array([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]])

out_shape = tuple(map(lambda x: x + 1, max(nodes.keys())))

out = np.zeros(out_shape)

for pos, idx in nodes.items():
    out[pos] = A[idx - 1]

assert np.array_equal(out, T)
```

Comment: I was wondering why you define ```T``` to begin with here? I only have ```nodes``` and ```A``` as inputs. I want the code to give me ```T``` as the output.

Comment: Just to check that `assert np.array_equal(out, T)`